# Optimization: Painting synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, paint

I'm having some heavy optimization issues with painting. A sample of my code looks like this:

```
BufferedImage img1;
synchronized(game.players){
    synchronized(game.monsters){
        synchronized(game.playersHealth){
            synchronized(game.monstersHealth){
                synchronized(game.overlays){
                    synchronized(game.projectiles){
                        img1 = game.drawAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
game.setImage(img1);
game.repaint();
```

I know this probably looks horrid to most of you. The thing is, I have multiple Sets of different Objects that contain data (players, monsters etc.), and this block of code ^ runs in an 'infinite' loop on a seperate thread that organizes all of the imagery and then tells the game to paint itself again. I need help. Can you guys point me in the right direction towards properly doing something like this?

Comment: Oh my.... Maybe synchronize on the class? Maybe with a `Thread.yield()`?

Comment: What other lock ordering is used in the program?  For example, does a block of code ever synchronize `game.projectiles` without first locking `overlays`, `monstersHealth`, etc?  If not, then coalesce all this mess into a single lock.

Comment: Yes there are other parts of the code that synchronize with only one or two of the fields. But wouldn't it be less efficient to synchronize with all of the fields if I only wanted to access the projectiles or something?

Comment: Yes, it's less efficient if you're locking too much, since you're preventing other threads from using those resources; I was trying to find out of all of the threads were always using all of the resources, in which case it would be more efficient to condense the many locks into one.  What sort of data structures are you locking - are they hashmaps that can be replaced with a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), or queues/arrays/linked-lists that can be replaced with a ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: Why don't you just use a concurrenthashmap and store all your objects in there or if you want different maps for different types of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the `synchronized` keyword: it is only meant to provide exclusive access to a lock on the given object. If no other section of code tries to synchronize on the same lock, then only threads executing that specific section of code will be *synchronized*.

This means that:

- your other threads must lock any of these collections for the statements which manipulate one or more elements in that collection.
- the only thing which is locked is the collection: a thread T holding a reference to an element can still modify it concurrently to the rendering thread R while it is executing the synchronized code, if T  is outside a synchronized block.

Now, regarding your code, one solution is to push the synchronization down within the rendering function, by locking individual objects. You probably have a loop on each collection which processes the elements one by one, or something to that effect: that's where you may want to put synchronization efforts, or perhaps within the elements themselves. You might for instance split the game logic from the game rendering, by having each game entity implement two interfaces: rendering and logic, and let the rendering thread only access the rendering interface, and the logic game access the logic interface.

By separating the two concerns in specific interfaces, you might be able to better distinguish which bit of information gets used by what, and where things need to be synchronized properly.

Another solution, with probably less refactoring involved, consists in turning the logic and rendering threads into a producer consumer setting: each thread work through the entity list, and when done with one, push it to the other thread queue. Each entity would move back and forth between the threads, and let the threads work on them without any other form of synchronization than their respective input queue.

If you have different ordering constraints on each thread, then nothing much can be done on that, beyond trying to regroup the entities in dependency groups, and process them in batches (a thread process a batch, and pass that batch as a single item to the other thread queue), ie. try to separate entities which are not dependent on each other.

Comment: It will be difficult to go into finer details without knowing more about your setup.